# How to start android app with view based on result of onAuthStateChanged?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I would like to load a view based on the result of `onAuthStateChanged` after `firebase.init` resolves.

```
firebase.init({}).then(
  function (instance) {
    var listener = {
        onAuthStateChanged: function(data) {
            console.log(data.loggedIn ? "Logged in to firebase" : "Logged out from firebase");
            if (data.loggedIn) {
                console.log("User info", data.user);
                firebase.removeAuthStateListener(listener);
                application.start({ moduleName: "views/home/home" });
            }

            else {
                firebase.removeAuthStateListener(listener);
                application.start({ moduleName: "views/splash/splash" });
            }
        },
        thisArg: this
    };

    firebase.addAuthStateListener(listener);
  }, 
  function (error) {
    console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
  }
);
```

However, I receive this error: `Error: A Frame must be used to navigate to a Page.`

The app launches fine when I use this code (albeit without the login stuff):

```
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

firebase.init({
 }).then(
    function (instance) {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
    }
);

application.start({ moduleName: "views/splash/splash" });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm no nativescript expert, but it looks like nativescript expect you to call `application.start(...)` right at the start of your app, not inside the authentication callback that will only be called later (asynchronously).
So I would say: call `application.start(...)` to display a loading screen, and when the authentication callback is called, remove the loading screen and display the screen you want instead.

Comment: @Sistr. That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks for giving me confidence with this technique.

Comment: Edit: Also, I ended up saving user state to a global variable (`global.logged = true`) so that I access user auth state synchronously when needed in the app. I use the same technique with web apps by storing user auth state in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");

var viewToLoad;

firebase.init({
 }).then(
    function (instance) {
      console.log("firebase.init done");
      viewToLoad = ... ; // set your view on success
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
      viewToLoad = ... ; // set your view on error
    }
);

application.start({ moduleName: viewToLoad });
```

Comment: Nick, thank you for the suggestion but I need it to address the auth state. Also, I do not believe this would work anyways due to the asynchronous firebase call, and `application.start()` would be called before `firebase.init` resolves and sets `viewToLoad`